# Realm Java query by arithmetic expression

Tags: realm

Suppose I have two classes:

```
public class Item extends RealmObject {
    public long enableTime;
    public long life;
}

public class Container extends RealmObject {
    public RealmList<Item > items;
}
```

And I want to query Containers by the expiration of their items. And I prepared to calculate itemExpiration of one Item this way:

```
if (item.enableTime == 0){
     itemExpiration = 0;
}else{
     itemExpiration = now - item.enableTime - item.life;
}
```

And averageExpiration of a Container is the average itemExpiration of it's items.

So is there any way I can query the top most (by averageExpiration) 10 (if there are) Containers that the averageExpiration is larger than 0.

Comment: Currently Realm doesn't support your use case. You can track the progress of the feature in this issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1615

Comment: You would have to calculate the average and store it as a field in your `Container`, most possibly in a repository when you modify the items that belong to a given container.